# Trying to submit file via form asynchronously using Angular $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, post, asynchronous

I am trying to submit a file asynchronously via Angular. This is the HTML:

```
<form ng-submit="videoSubmit()">
    <input id="upl-0"  type="file" name="upl" accept="video/ogg, video/mp4, video/webm">
    <input type="submit" value='Submit' />
</form>
```

My Angular code:

```
 $scope.videoSubmit = function() {

    var file = document.getElementById('upl-0').files[0];

    var formData = new FormData();
    console.log(file);
    formData.append("upl", file, file.name);
    console.log(formData);
    console.log(formData.getAll("upl"));

    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: "api/asset/upload-test",
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        })
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
 };
```

This definitely attaches the file to the formData object because it is displaying the right file data in the console.

Now I want to do something with this on the server, but in the meantime I just want to actually get this working, so this is all that's on the server:

```
 router.post('/api/asset/upload-test', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.data);
    console.log(req.body);
 });
```

However somehow the server just doesn't receive the file, and displays `undefined` for req.data and `{}` for req.body. Why is this and how can I get this actually working in the same implementation, so without having to encode or decode the file in something like base64 or similar. Thanks.

Comment: You can do that without 3rd party middleware, as you are already trying to, but in case you are looking for one you can try [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) which will simplify your work. Also as BuriB already said in his answer you should be looking for `req.files`

Comment: How can I do it without 3rd party middleware? req.files is also undefined.

Comment: If you want to use multer there's a very simple example in its github page [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#usage)

Answer (score 0):

should be in req.files and in order for that you'll need to use express.bodyParser(). If you use express of course.